# GCLB Missing SameSite and Secure Flags

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have faced the issue with GCLB which is running with instance groups. I have multiple instances running in the backend. On the webserver Hearder are setup properly like SameSite=None;HttpOnly;Secure but in GCP load balancer only HttpOnly flag is coming. Please see the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the problem that you have? The cookie `GCLB` is for cookie based affinity for the load balancer and not for your use. Should the GLB set `secure`? No, as the Google Load Balancer supports HTTP and HTTPS. Should the GLB set `same-site`? No, as this requires that `Secure` also be set.

Comment: ok, but I am facing an issue with our chrome extension. When we run the instance group with one instance everything is working fine but when the instance group has multiple instances running its session is not working, it keeps disconnecting seems Extention trying different instances to connect. It should have to use the session cookie to serve the session from the same instance.

Comment: I do not write Chrome extensions. You should have included your comment in your original question as this is not a Google Cloud Platform problem, it is a Chrome extension problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley What if someone is embedding a site served through GCP load balancer via a cross-domain iframe? Then the GCLB cookie will be rejected by the browser, and sticky sessions won't work properly.

Comment: @RobSiklos that is really my case.